# ng-messages show error only if touched and transition on initial display of errors

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate

I would like to use ng-messages to show validation messages for an Angular form. However

- I would like these messages to be hidden for each field until $touched is true.
- I would like there to be CSS transitions on appearance/disappearance of each message

I have the following HTML

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input name="myInput" type="text" required ng-model="myValue">
  <ng-messages for="myForm.myInput.$error" ng-if="myForm.myInput.$touched">
    <ng-message when="required">Required</ng-message>
  </ng-messages>
</form>
```

With CSS

```
ng-message.ng-enter {
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
}

ng-message.ng-enter-prepare {
  opacity: 0;
}

ng-message.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

ng-message.ng-leave {
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  opacity: 1;
}

ng-message.ng-leave-prepare {
  opacity: 1;
}

ng-message.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Which can be seen at https://plnkr.co/edit/Y3lEIEencPtRfP5RhJ3f?p=preview

This works, except for the initial display of the error message, when there is no transition and the message immediately appears. For example if you click into the input, and then tab away.

How can I have the transition happen on the initial display of the message? I would prefer to not have to change the definition of what it means for a field to be valid, so the logic for allowing the submission of the form is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the for attribute passed to the ng-messages directive, so if the input is not touched, ng-messages has no errors to show:

```
<ng-messages for="myForm.myInput.$touched ? myForm.myInput.$error : null">
  <ng-message when="required">Required</ng-message>
</ng-messages>
```

This can be seen at https://plnkr.co/edit/80SsV9qSVx5kBAvSTGUp?p=preview